# Ubuntu unattended upgrades not working on Ubuntu 14.04.4

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, upgrade, unattended

I have enabled unattended upgrades in an Ubuntu 14.04 server, and it seems to be running, but it does not update the packages that can be updated.

For example right now I get

```
46 packages can be updated.
```

apt-get upgrade outputs before confirmation:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  galera-3 libgd3 libjbig0 libmariadbclient18 libmysqlclient18 libpcre3
  libssl1.0.0 libssl1.0.2 libzip4 mariadb-client-10.1 mariadb-client-core-10.1
  mariadb-common mariadb-server-core-10.1 mysql-common newrelic-daemon
  newrelic-php5 newrelic-php5-common newrelic-sysmond openssl php-common
  php-igbinary php-imagick php-json php-memcache php-memcached php-msgpack
  php-xdebug php5.6-bcmath php5.6-cli php5.6-common php5.6-curl php5.6-fpm
  php5.6-gd php5.6-imap php5.6-json php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql
  php5.6-opcache php5.6-readline php5.6-recode php5.6-soap php5.6-xml
  php5.6-zip php7.0-common php7.0-json
46 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades contains:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

and today's unnattended-upgrades.log ends with

```
2016-05-29 17:05:37,434 DEBUG pkgs that look like they should be upgraded:
2016-05-29 17:05:37,448 DEBUG fetch.run() result: 0
2016-05-29 17:05:37,448 DEBUG blacklist: []
2016-05-29 17:05:37,449 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

What gives? How can I figure out why unattended upgrades is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probable solution is that your `Allowed-Origins` filter does not match the origin tags in the packages.

To debug this on my system, I created a script (see gist: [dist_info](https://gist.github.com/plattrap/61851bbea442c9138f1b6e6fd75bbabc)) to dump the current origins rules, as used by `unattended-updates` and also to dump the origins for a package/s when requested.

Comment: Handy script, thank you! Nevertheless that does not seem to be the issue... here is the output